# Auto populate for more than one Text Field and drop down list

Tags: php, jquery

Im having a problem when im trying to auto populate more than one text field as well as dropdown list ... This UI fetches data from DB for auto populating ... actually the problem arises when i click the + button for additional textfield and dropdown list ... for the first text field and drop down list im getting auto populated correctly but i face problem when i try for the second row ...  please correct my errors

`

```
    </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#add1').click(function() {



                $("#box").append(
                        $('<div><input type="text" name="property_id" id="property_id"/>\n\
                            <select disabled="" name="unit_id" id="unit_id">\n\
                                    <option></option>\n\
                            </select><img src="remove.png" width="20" height="20" border="0" align="top" class="add1" id="remove" /><br></div>')



                        );


            });



            $('body').on('click', '#remove', function() {

                $(this).parent('div').remove();


            });


        });

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">







        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            $('#property_id').autocomplete({
                source: 'unit.php',
                minLength: 1,
                select: function(evt, ui)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "property.php",
                        data: {propertyid: ui.item.property_id},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(data) {
                            var pname = ui.item.value;
                            console.log("combo data === ", pname, data);
                            $('select[name="unit_id"]').empty();
                            $('select[name="unit_id"]').append($('<option>').text("Select"));
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                $('select[name="unit_id"]').append(
                                        $('<option>', {value: data[i]["unit_id"]}).text(data[i]["unit_id"])
                                        );
                            }
                            $('select[name="unit_id"]').removeAttr('disabled');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
    <input type="text" name="property_id" id="property_id"/>
    <select disabled="" name="unit_id" id="unit_id">
        <option></option>
    </select>
    <img src="add.png" width="20" height="20" border="0" align="top" class="add" id="add1" /><br>
    </div>
</body>
```

`

Comment: Why do you use $( just after append() method ?

Comment: It treats as a variable ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you bind autocomplete on load. So the new item you created will not be bound with ui code.

You should bind the new item you created with the autocomplete. Like you did on load.

You can make binding a function and call it on load and after you created the item. Like,

```
var bindAutoComplete = function(elem) {
    $(elem).autocomplete({
                source: 'unit.php',
                minLength: 1,
                select: function(evt, ui)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "property.php",
                        data: {propertyid: ui.item.property_id},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(data) {
                            var pname = ui.item.value;
                            console.log("combo data === ", pname, data);
                            $('select[name="unit_id"]').empty();
                            $('select[name="unit_id"]').append($('<option>').text("Select"));
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                $('select[name="unit_id"]').append(
                                        $('<option>', {value: data[i]["unit_id"]}).text(data[i]["unit_id"])
                                        );
                            }
                            $('select[name="unit_id"]').removeAttr('disabled');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
}
```

then in your on load

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            bindAutoComplete($('#property_id')[0]);

});
```

and in your add item method

```
$('#add1').click(function() {

var newItem = $('<div><input type="text" name="property_id" id="property_id"/>\n\
                            <select disabled="" name="unit_id" id="unit_id">\n\
                                    <option></option>\n\
                            </select><img src="remove.png" width="20" height="20" border="0" align="top" class="add1" id="remove" /><br></div>');

bindAutoComplete(newItem.find("#property_id")[0]);

                $("#box").append(newItem);


            });
```

Warning, this code seems messy but to make you get the idea of binding this should work.

Comment: @Ananth That means you solved the issue? or still need more help?

Answer (score 0):

When you click add you are creating elements that have the same id as existing ones so this will fail. Give your created element a unique id.

You'll also need unique names if you are submitting, or add them as an array

I've also changed your remove id and changed the class:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {

        var i = 0;

        $('#add1').click(function() {


            $("#box").append(


                $('<div><input type="text" class="property_input" name="property_id[]" id="property_id' + i + '"/>\n\
                        <select disabled="" class="unit_select" name="unit_id[]" id="unit_id' + i + '">\n\
                                <option></option>\n\
                        </select><img src="remove.png" width="20" height="20" border="0" align="top" class="remove" /><br></div>')



                    );

            i++;

        });



        $('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {

            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            i--;

        });


    });

</script>
```

I'm not sure exactly how autocomplete works but I reckon you'll have to give your select and inputs a class (as i have done) and loop through them, grab the id and call your ajax